# Placement of two elements in one sequence

Tags: html, css, web

I would like the text and icons (login, shop) to be the same level as the 'Logo' but just to the right side. I tried by adding to the '.shop-icon' {margin: -30px auto;} but it all destroyed the page and then the entire 'nav bar' and 'article' covered the header.

I'm still learning, but at the beginning I know I've broken something.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background: #2B2B2B;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}

.header-front {
  max-width: 992px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h1.logo {
  color: #F6F6F6;
  font-size: 4.8rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: left;
}

.shop-icon {
  text-align: right;
}

.bag,
.account {
  color: #F6F6F6;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 10px;
}

.main-menu {
  background-color: #F7FCFA;
  width: 100%;
}

p {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header class="header-front">
    <h1 class="logo">Logo </h1>
    <div class="shop-icon">
      <a href="_blank" class="account">
            Login <i class="fa fa-user-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>

      <a href="_blank" class="bag">
            shop <i class="fa fa-shopping-bag" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>
    </div>

  </header>

  <nav class="main-menu">
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <article>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer ultrices elit eget tortor varius ornare. Etiam commodo sapien dui, in gravida purus malesuada eget. Vestibulum mollis ipsum consectetur ipsum tempor, non sagittis nunc gravida. Aenean
      dolor arcu, faucibus a urna nec, pulvinar mollis erat. Pellentesque scelerisque sapien purus, eget porta tellus lacinia ut. Aenean vel ipsum tortor. Ut faucibus sagittis lorem, a molestie enim commodo vel. Maecenas ac placerat nisl. Phasellus felis
      elit, tincidunt nec ullamcorper vitae, interdum non leo. </p>
  </article>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `.logo` (`h1`) and `.shop-icons` (`div`) are both *block* elements, so they will occupy the full horizontal space/width they have available. You could change them to *inline-elements* (`span`) or style them this way (`display: inline-block`), you could also `float` them respectively (`.logo {float: left;} .shop-icon {float: right;}`) but then the containing parent element (`.header-front`) will collapse and you'll have to *clear* the floats. Another method you could try is to use `flex-box` by declaring `display: flex;` on the containing parent element (`.header-front`).

Comment: ...But `flex-box` is the "easy" way out and you might not actually learn anything new about the inherit nature of css alignment...

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError i think he better do with flex like you said. Better learn this new stuff then try using old style with floating or inline-block.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Always good to know how to do things the old ways too - beneficial to have more tools in your toolkit so that you are never stuck with only "one way" of doing things (old or new).

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError i totally agree. But better "hide" the old thing until he learn well the new ones which they are easier and better and then he will for sure discover the remaining ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif Sure - there are many ways of getting there and we all have to start somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use flex. Specify `display:flex` in the container and `align-items: center` to make the elements vertically aligned. Then you specify `flex:1` to shop-icon so it takes the remaining space and you already have its elements right aligned.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background: #2B2B2B;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}

.header-front {
  max-width: 992px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

h1.logo {
  color: #F6F6F6;
  font-size: 4.8rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: left;
}

.shop-icon {
  text-align: right;
  flex: 1;
}

.bag,
.account {
  color: #F6F6F6;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 10px;
}

.main-menu {
  background-color: #F7FCFA;
  width: 100%;
}

p {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header class="header-front">
    <h1 class="logo">Logo </h1>
    <div class="shop-icon">
      <a href="_blank" class="account">
            Login <i class="fa fa-user-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>

      <a href="_blank" class="bag">
            shop <i class="fa fa-shopping-bag" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>
    </div>

  </header>

  <nav class="main-menu">
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <article>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer ultrices elit eget tortor varius ornare. Etiam commodo sapien dui, in gravida purus malesuada eget. Vestibulum mollis ipsum consectetur ipsum tempor, non sagittis nunc gravida. Aenean
      dolor arcu, faucibus a urna nec, pulvinar mollis erat. Pellentesque scelerisque sapien purus, eget porta tellus lacinia ut. Aenean vel ipsum tortor. Ut faucibus sagittis lorem, a molestie enim commodo vel. Maecenas ac placerat nisl. Phasellus felis
      elit, tincidunt nec ullamcorper vitae, interdum non leo. </p>
  </article>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you! That was it, I still have to train the flexbox

Comment: @k.drm welcome ;) and yes i advice you to read more about it as it's a powerfull tool to easily make complex layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `position` `absolute` on `shop-icon` element.

```
.shop-icon {
  position: absolute;
  left: 120px;
  top: 26px;
}
```

If the desired location is on the right hand side of the page, you can use `right: 10px`, in place of the `left` position.

Here's a snippet:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background: #2B2B2B;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}

.header-front {
  max-width: 992px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h1.logo {
  color: #F6F6F6;
  font-size: 4.8rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: left;
}

.shop-icon {
  position: absolute;
  left: 120px;
  top: 26px;
}

.bag,
.account {
  color: #F6F6F6;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 10px;
}

.main-menu {
  background-color: #F7FCFA;
  width: 100%;
}

p {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header class="header-front">
    <h1 class="logo">Logo </h1>
    <div class="shop-icon">
      <a href="_blank" class="account">
            Login <i class="fa fa-user-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>

      <a href="_blank" class="bag">
            shop <i class="fa fa-shopping-bag" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>
    </div>

  </header>

  <nav class="main-menu">
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <article>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer ultrices elit eget tortor varius ornare. Etiam commodo sapien dui, in gravida purus malesuada eget. Vestibulum mollis ipsum consectetur ipsum tempor, non sagittis nunc gravida. Aenean
      dolor arcu, faucibus a urna nec, pulvinar mollis erat. Pellentesque scelerisque sapien purus, eget porta tellus lacinia ut. Aenean vel ipsum tortor. Ut faucibus sagittis lorem, a molestie enim commodo vel. Maecenas ac placerat nisl. Phasellus felis
      elit, tincidunt nec ullamcorper vitae, interdum non leo. </p>
  </article>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i think they want them to stay on the right, so maybe make `right:0` instead of left

Comment: @TemaniAfif thanks for the observation. I'm actually in doubt since the OP says "just to the right" of the logo. But yes, if the desired location is on the right hand side, you can use `right:10px` for instance.

Comment: @TemaniAfif have right i want to stay on the right, sorry for the misunderstanding it's my fault i wrote it wrong